# Get component-wise maximum of vector in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I need to get the maximum of a `vec3` in GLSL. Currently I am doing

```
max(max(col.r, col.g),col.b)
```

It works. But I am wondering if there a better way to do this with one built-in function call?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is the best you are going to do in GLSL, unfortunately.

I have gotten used to writing that sort of thing. However, if it bothers you, you can always write your own function that does that.

#### For example:

```
float max3 (vec3 v) {
  return max (max (v.x, v.y), v.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While for `vec3` you need two `max` operations, for `vec4` you do not need three, two are enough:

```c
vec2 maxPairs = max(v.xy, v.zw);
float maxValue = max(maxPairs.x, maxPairs.y);
```

It may even be extended to finding max of two `vec4` with three `max`:

```c
vec4 v = max(a, b);
vec2 maxPairs = max(v.xy, v.zw);
float maxValue = max(maxPairs .x, maxPairs.y);
```

Note: I doubt it will make any difference on todays hardware, and if it does, the optimizer will probably rearrange the code for you anyway. I feel a bit nostalgic about times when "code golf" like this was a regular part of my work.