# Efficient component selector in glsl

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, linear-algebra

A long time ago I ran into a snippet for glsl that efficiently computed the absolute wise maximum component of a vector and zeroed out the other components.

For example the following inputs would yield the following outputs:

```
vec3(1, 0, 0) -> vec3(1, 0, 0)
vec3(-1, 0.5, 0) -> vec3(-1, 0, 0)
vec3(2, 0.5, 0) -> vec3(2, 0, 0)
```

it relied mostly on mathematical operations to achieve this by leveraging the lin alg hardware built into most gpus as much as possible, but I don't remember how the snippet looked like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the calculate the absolute value of the vector and the [component-wise maximum of vector in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006184/get-component-wise-maximum-of-vector-in-glsl). Finally you can use [`greaterThanEqual`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/greaterThanEqual.xhtml):

```c
vec3 vabs = abs(v);
float m = max(vabs.x, max(vabs.y, vabs.z));
vec3 vmax = v * vec3(greaterThanEqual(vabs, vec3(m)));
```